# Datatables, how can I make one column sort another with icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables, icons

Right now I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
        "order": [],
        "autowidth": false,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "columnDefs": [
        { "orderData":[ 1 ],   "targets": [ 0 ] },
        ]
    } );
});
```

This makes the first column sort the second column. It works as expected, except the sorting icon shows up on the first column instead of the second.

I need the sorting icon to show up in the second column, does anybody have any idea how to do that? Thanks

Comment: This is what you need https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Comment: That's for if I need to add invisible values for search/sort. That's not at all what I need.

Comment: I agree with @BurakÖztürk . You can put same data in `data-order` in first columna and in the second column.

Comment: "*except the sorting icon shows up on the first column instead of the second.*" of course, you are sorting on the first column.  How should it be any different? You could sort the second column programmatically instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Did I not make my question clear?*". Your question is very clear, the answer is still the same: You cannot have your cake and eat it. You must programmatically sort the second column if you want sorting arrows on the second column. Simply trigger a click on the second column when the mouse is hitting the first. Here is an example :

```js
$('#example thead th:eq(0)').off().on('mousedown', function(e) {
  $('#example thead th:eq(1)').trigger('click');
  return false; //prevent focus rect
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8cxn4751/**

Comment: perfect Thank You! I had to use the th ID instead of the code you have for some reason, I'm guessing datatables had set the ID for the th but I had manually specified them

Comment: Edit : had to use Class, not ID